# What are the ways to Send FCM Notification From Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing chat app which sending files and messages through Firebase Platform. Storage for storing image and videos and Database for storing image or video links and messages.

During development I need help in these issues I face during development of the chat app:

- **Sending Notification to offline device**: I have both sender and receiver FCM Token at app side while sending message to Firebase database. I can check on app side that app is foreground or background so if app is in background, I need to send push notification to app. I have implemented FCM on app side, but I need some logic how to send push notification if app is in background (if I can get code sample that would be better).
- **Show message in sequel as it sent**: I have array list which get its elements from Firebase database and text is showing fine, but if there is some link (link will run in background and returned with details of link) its more time to show in app than simple message or photo. So how can I synchronize my ArrayList to show data as it retrieved from Firebase database.